# Python: breadth first search

Tags: python, python-3.x

Node contains:
State(an integer unique ID of the node of the graph), Parent (a node in the search tree that generated this node), Path cost(a cost associated with current node)

```
"""A node in a search tree. Contains a pointer to the parent (the node
that this is a successor of) and to the state for this node
representing actual graph node (graph node ID)."""

#given function
def __init__(self, state, parent=None, path_cost=0):
    """Create a search tree Node"""
    self.state = state
    self.parent = parent
    self.path_cost = path_cost
    self.depth = 0
    if parent:
        self.depth = parent.depth + 1

 #given function
 def child_node(self, graph, state):
    """Create a new search node and mark it as a child.
     The child node will have current node as a parent."""

    next_node = Node(state,
                     parent=self,
                     path_cost=self.path_cost + 1)

    return next_node

# expand function was given to us
def expand(self, graph):
    """List the nodes reachable in one step from this node i.e
       neighbours of the current node."""

    return [self.child_node(graph, state)
            for state in graph.neighbors(self.state)]
```

Here we have implement the bfs function as our assignment.

```
def bfs(graph, start, dest): 
    to_check = []
    visited = set()

    to_check.insert(0, start)

    #while to_check has nodes
    while to_check:
        next_node = queue.pop()
        visited.add(next_node)

        for sibling in next_node.expand(graph):

            if sibling not in visited and sibling not in to_check:

                if sibling == dest:
                    return sibling
                else: 
                    to_check.insert(0, next_node)
```

The code I ran using the above functions:

```
start_graph_state = 3470524959
destination_graph_state = 5674155097
start = Node(state=start_graph_state)
dest = Node(state=destination_graph_state)
solution_node = bfs(graph, start, dest)
```

I'm supposed to plot an appropriate graph, but I've commented out and instead I was running function to check whether the nodes were being iterated correctly. But I keep getting stuck on the starting node because it is never placed in set nor is it removed from the to_check queue even after I have popped it out. (Even when the destination node is directly one edge away, I get an infinite loop) I'm very new to Python and I feel that I'm just stuck on simple syntax problems, but I'm confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where does `queue` come from? Maybe `to_check.pop()` instead of `queue.pop()`?

Comment: Please provide the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code does not have an infinite loop: all it does is define two functions and quit without executing.  You show no input, no output, no quantitative expected result, no execution trace, ... If you complete your question, we'll attempt to fix the *specified* problem.

Comment: What exactly does `self.child_node()` do?  If it's creating new node objects each time, it's likely that `not in visited` and `not in to_check` will not find the nodes, even if an equivalent node is present in the list or set.  You'd have to implement appropriate `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods for that to work.

Comment: Please add a brief problem description to your question.This would help people to assess if this is a question for them to answer and therefor increases your chances that you get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you use a FIFO queue (such as the one available in collections).

The general structure of the traversal would be as follows:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()

q.append(firstNode)
visited = set()

while q:
    node = q.popleft()
    if node in visited: continue
    visited.add(node)
    for nextNode in node.neighbours:
        q.append(nextNode)  

    # perform required processing on node
```